# Proving multivariate limits

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $$f(x,y)=\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$$  where$$x^2+y^2>0$$

Explain why the fact that $f_{xy}(0,0)$ $\neq$ $f_{yx}(0,0)$ does not contradict Clairaunt's Theorem.

My Solution

I first calculate that $f_{xy}(0,0)=-1$ and $f_{yx}(0,0)=0$ hence showing that $f_{xy}(0,0)$ and  $f_{yx}(0,0)$ does not give the same value. On first glance it seems to  contradict Clairaunt's Theorem. Then i think of a case where Clairaunt's Theorem does not work. And that s only when the function $$f(x,y)$$ is not continous when both x and y are equals to 0. Hence limit does not exists when x=y=0. So i tried the two path test to prove discounity but which path i used the limit still give me the same value of 0. Hence im stuck here, Could anyone help

Comment: You might want to retry your derivatives, I got $f_{xy}(x,y)=f_{yx}(x,y)$.

Comment: The point is that the derivatives are not equal when both x and y are 0.

Comment: But both give $\frac{x^6 + 9 x^4 y^2 - 9 x^2 y^4 - y^6}{(x^2 + y^2)^3}$ for the second derivative, so I don't see how this is a contradiction. Clairaut's Theorem only guarantees they will be equal on the domain of $f_{xy}$ which does not include the origin.

Comment: But for ur expression if u were to sub in x and y equals to 0, the expression will be undefined as the denominator becomes 0.

Comment: And there you see the problem, the derivatives are not continuous at the origin. Clairaut's Theorem requires continuous second partial derivatives.

Comment: Oh thanks. I think that should be the explanation.

Comment: See [Requirement of continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives).